# Postfix, set privileges for piping

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, pipe

I configured postfix on my box to call a php script on incoming e-mails, using virtual aliases. The script is being called, but it runs as "nobody" and thus I can't send signals to another program from my script that runs as a real user.

I found the setting default_privs and set it to the user that runs the program I want to signal, and this works, but that still allows me to signal only programs of that one user.

How can I solve this? I guess putting root in default_privs and having the called script su into the appropriate user account would be a stupid move, but what alternatives are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a transport in `master.cf` for piping. There you can set the option `user=` to run the pipe under that user. Exactly as described in the manual: http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html

As stated in the other manual for `default_privs`: "**DO NOT SPECIFY A PRIVILEGED USER OR THE POSTFIX OWNER.**"

Comment: So basically there's no short way of doing it? I read that in the manual but just writing it there without providing proper alternatives isn't of much help.

Comment: Why is configuring a transport _not_ the short way? It is a two-liner.